# Any way to tell what date I added some of my Favourites in IE 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to group Favourites that I found on the same day together so I want to be able to tell when I added each of my Favourites?  I want to be able to view when all my Favourites were added at one time; I don't want to click each one separately to find out.  Any app or simple way to do this?

Win 7 Pro.
IE 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `Favorites` folder in Explorer, and look at their dates:

[image]

Make sure the **Date Created** column is enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**WinMerge**, will tell you the date saved.(they have a free version).
Click top folder and browse to your Favorites folder, select as shown below.
Do the same with the second folder.
Set filter to none, as shown.

[image: Folder settings]

Click OK.
They all match each other and this will list the Favorites and date stored.
They are listed in order by date not name of favorite.

[image: end display]

Home page of [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/)
Download page of [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads/)
This will give you the dates saved.
The 'Help file' may explain if you to move files around.
See: 'Overview of comparing and merging'.
re- merging files.
You may have to use a blank folder as second selection folder to set a difference, it can also be in the Favorites folder and called 'Test', etc
This will enable the merge icons on the menubar,

[image: menubar with folder selection]

I have used it to compare and merge but am not able to explain if it will auto-sort for you.
Sorry not of much more help.
Hope this helps

Comment: Appreciate your answer but the other is simpler.